# Trouble Using COM_AccessibleObjectFromWindow()

Tags: autohotkey

I inherited a project that involves a .ahk script to open a file from a location and load it into a program. Sadly, I've had to learn from scratch and I've come upon a section of code that I can't figure out or get to work for the life of me. 
Here's the snippet:

```
if Not oLV:=COM_AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd) ; checks if its valid
    ExitApp
```

When I run the script on a PC using Windows 7, this works fine. When I ported it over to a machine with Windows 10, this one line stops working. Everything else in the script works fine. I'm printing oLV.accChildCount to a textbox to see how many items are in my list. There are 5 items and this is shown on the old machine, but isn't showing on the new machine. The textbox just pops up blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems like **oLV := Acc_ObjectFromWindow(hwnd)** is what I needed to do. Still weird how **COM_AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd)** doesn't work on the newer machine.

Comment: Hi, @Jimbo57, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for taking the time to provide a useful answer. Head over to the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get your first badge!